# How to find the port number given the ip address

Tags: linux, command-line, embedded

I could find the ip address of my board by using ifconfig but I need the port number as well to set Linux TCF agent. I tried netstat with several options but could not find as it returns too many and cannot scroll the screen to the top. So is there a way to find the port number given the ip address?

Comment: I'm guessing you want to find a listening port. You can list listening port using `netstat -tuln`. Pipe it through `more` or `less` if the output list is too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prefer using `ss`

`netstat` is [deprecated](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/files/?source=navbar) (no update since 2011), as said in the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/netstat.8.html), in the NOTE section.

So you probably should use `ss`, which is part of the `iproute2` package.

You can use the following command:

```
ss -nltp
```

- `-n` will prevent names resolution
- `-l` displays listening sockets
- `-t` is used for TCP transport (if you have UDP instead, use `-u`, or you may even use both at same time)
- `-p` will show you the process name which uses this socket

## You may still use `netstat`

Note that if you can't use `ss` for any reasons, the command line arguments are exactly the same for netstat, eg.:

```
netstat -nltp
```

## Filter the output

To look for a specific program or port numbers, you can apply filter on the output using `grep`:

```bash
ss -nltp | grep "<process_name or port_number>"
```

Or as said by @davidt930 in the comments, use `less` to easily browse the output:

```
ss -nltp | less
```

## Other tool that may help you

Just in case someone needs this, I wanted to say that you can also use tools for ports scan. So you can even run the command from outside the system.

The most famous one is probably [Nmap](https://nmap.org).

I know it's a bit overkill in this situation ^^, but I add that just in case someone is in trouble and needs a different solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it returns the local address and port number but I want inet address and port number.

Comment: Address displayed in the `Local Address` columns mean the listening address. So if your machine is listening on all *ipv4* interfaces, it will display `0.0.0.0`, or `[::]` for *ipv6*. This is related to your service config, not to `ss` itself. If the displayed local address is `0.0.0.0`, then you have to check the output of the `ip a` command, and you can expect the service to listen on all displayed ip addresses. I hope I understood correctly your question, otherwise don't hesitate to tell me ;-).

Comment: Thank you, I got it now.